# Replacing new line with comma seperator

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a text file that the records in the following format. Please note that there are no empty files within the Name, ID and Rank section.

```
"NAME","STUDENT1"
"ID","123"
"RANK","10"
"NAME","STUDENT2"
"ID","124"
"RANK","11"
```

I have to convert the above file to the below format

```
"STUDENT1","123","10"
"STUDENT2","124","11"
```

I understand that this can be achieved using shell script by reading the records and writing it to another output file. But can this can done using awk or sed ?

Comment: it can be done with `cut+paste/pr` too.. when asking question here, you are expected to show what is the code you are having problem with.. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print $2}' file
"STUDENT1","123","10"
"STUDENT2","124","11"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$1=="\"RANK\""{print $2;next}{printf "%s,",$2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk, printing newline each 3 lines:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s",$2;if (NR%3){printf ","}else{print""};}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk -F, '{ORS=$0~/^"RANK/?"\n":FS;print $NF}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -E 'N;N;;y/\n/ /;s/([^,]*)(,[^ ]*)/\2/g;s/,//' infile
```